# Rounding artefacts when converting Double Precision column to Date

Tags: firebird

In a table dates are being saved as datatype `DOUBLE PRECISION`. Trying to convert it into date format but incorrect dates coming up when timestamp is greater than 12PM.(i.e gives date for next day if timestamp is greater or equal to `12:00:00.000`)

This is what I've tried

1. dateColumn + CAST ('30.12.1899' AS DATE)
2. DATE'1899-12-30' + dateColumn

**Example**

```
SELECT  po.DELIVERYDATE as DOUBLE_FORMAT, 
        po.DELIVERYDATE + CAST ('30.12.1899' AS TIMESTAMP) as DATE_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT, 
        po.DELIVERYDATE + CAST ('30.12.1899' AS DATE) as DATE_FORMAT_1,
        DATE'1899-12-30' + po.DELIVERYDATE   as DATE_FORMAT_2
FROM    PURCHASE_ORDER po
```

**Result**

```
DOUBLE_FORMAT    DATE_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT      DATE_FORMAT_1   DATE_FORMAT_2
-------------    ------------------------   -------------   -------------
41485.421586     30.07.2013, 10:07:05.000   30.07.2013      30.07.2013
41488.487419     02.08.2013, 11:41:53.000   02.08.2013      02.08.2013
41488.489792     02.08.2013, 11:45:18.000   02.08.2013      02.08.2013
41506.630035     20.08.2013, 15:07:15.000   21.08.2013      21.08.2013 //<-- Incorrect
41516.514479     30.08.2013, 12:20:51.000   31.08.2013      31.08.2013 //<-- Incorrect
41521.402963     04.09.2013, 09:40:16.000   04.09.2013      04.09.2013
41520.511030     03.09.2013, 12:15:53.000   04.09.2013      04.09.2013 //<-- Incorrect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's arithmetic: when you are rounding a floating point to integer, then 2.5 is rounded to 3 not to 2.

So you have to

- either, explicitly convert float to integer in the direction you want **before** offsetting the base date
- or, since your data is both date and time - then convert it to `TIMESTAMP` first and only **after** that conversion do apply the rounding to `DATE`

Example:

```
select
  41516.514479,                                       -- 41516,514479
  cast( 41516.514479 as integer ),                    -- 41517
  round( 41516.514479 ),                              -- 41517   
  41516.514479 + DATE '1899-12-30',                   -- 31.08.2013
  floor( 41516.514479 ),                              -- 41516   
  floor( 41516.514479 ) + DATE '1899-12-30',          -- 30.08.2013
  41516.514479 + timestamp '1899-12-30',              -- 12:20 30.08.2013
  cast(41516.514479 + timestamp '1899-12-30' as DATE) -- 30.08.2013
from rdb$database
```